# Read xml node attribute

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I have an xml document that have nodes like this, `<ITEM id="1" name="bleh"... />`
What I want to do is get all id's attribute value for each ITEM node that exists in the document.

### So, how can I do that?

Edit: I've tried this way and it didn't works:

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
        Doc.Load("example.xml");
        XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.SelectNodes("/ITEM");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            string id = node.Attributes["id"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) in your call to [SelectSingleNode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) since your XML does contain a namespace on it:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("example.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("anyname", "http://tempuri.org/zitem.xsd");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//anyname:ITEM", ns))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

That's why you get no result.

The difference from my code to yours is that I am using `//` so instead of starting at the root of a document, a double forward slash `//` indicates to an `XPath` evaluator to look anywhere in an XML document.

Here is my `example.xml` as sample:

```
<root>
  <items>
    <ITEM id="1" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="2" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="3" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="4" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="5" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="6" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="7" name="bleh=" />
    <ITEM id="8" name="bleh=" />
  </items>
</root>
```

And here is how I am reading it:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("example.xml");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//ITEM[@id]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

With single slash, the above `XPath` would look like this:

```
/root/items/ITEM
```

I am also using `[@id]` to ensure that the `ITEM` element have an `ID` attribute but that is not necessary if you know they all have an `ID` attribute.

Comment: Your way works, but the problem is that your loading the xml structure from the code and not froom a file.

Comment: @Derezzed that does not matter, you can load it from a file as well, as long as the file is well formatted and a valid XML it should work the same. Since I don't know how your file is I made my own example to show you.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the file structure, the file's like this,
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TjHYW5TP

Comment: @Derezzed aha that's because you have a namespace see update on the code at the top.

Comment: It works, but there's something weird, it isn't printing from the "0" id, it just prints some of the ids but not all.
Anyways, thanks alot for helping me.

Comment: @Derezzed Well I would need to see a more complete example of your XML to be able to reproduce the issue and keep in mind the sample code above is to print only the ID attribute.

Comment: Nvm, I made it write the values to a text file and it wrotes all :), thank you very much again.

Comment: Can anyone help me to change the values or increment everytime you save;   my code ..... <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>

Comment: @ITForward create your own question with your code that is not working and wait for help, hijacking comments won't yield answers.