# How get the attribute value of XML node in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing the XML in C# this XML:

```
     <Resident Type="R">
          <Payment>1218</Payment>
     </Resident>
```

I am parsing this way(please answer this same way, not other methods)

```
  XmlDocument parsed_xml = new XmlDocument();
  parsed_xml.LoadXml(dto.xml);


  XmlNodeList test = parsed_xml.SelectNodes("/IER/Credit/Loan/LoanApp/Applicant/Personal/Individuals/Individual/Resident/Peyment");


  if (xnList != null)

            PAYMENT = xnList.Item(0).InnerText;
```

with this code I can get the Payment value that is 1218 but how I can get the attribute value of Type that is "R" ?

Comment: That's old school.  Use System.Linq.Xml instead.  Much quicker and easier way to handle xml.

Comment: check this http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

Comment: Check the following links, similar question is answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818618/read-xml-node-attribute

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600065/how-to-read-attribute-value-from-xmlnode-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look at the `ParentNode` to get the attribute.

```
string residentType = xnList[0].ParentNode.Attributes["Type"].Value;
```