# XML SelectSingleNode Is case sensitive

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, case-sensitive

While verifying the id in XML file, it is acting as a case-sensitive. I have added "translate" to make it as case-insensitive. Following is my code:

```
$Config = "xmlfile"
[xml]$configxml = Get-Content $config
$siteId = "Test"
$Siteid = $Siteid.ToLower()

$siteinfo = $configxml.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/environment[translate(@id='$($siteId)'])");

if(!$siteinfo) 
{
    Write-Host "id specified '$siteId' not found in '$config' Aborting..."
    exit -1
}
else
{
   Write-Host "site id is present"
}
```

I'm getting following error:

```
id specified 'Test' not found in 'xmlfile' Aborting...
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<configuration>

    <!--                           TEST                                 -->
    <environment id="TEST">
        <client>ABC</client>
        <type>Test</type>
        <filetype>ALL</filetype>
        <enable>yes</enable>
    </environment>

</configuration>
```

Can someone please suggest me possible solution how to make it as case-insensitive and how to use "translate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an XPATH, you could also select the nodes like properties:

```
$config = "xmlfile"
[xml]$configxml = Get-Content $config
$siteId = "Test"

$siteInfo = $configxml.configuration.environment | Where id -eq $siteId
```

This will also case-insensitive match your id...

Answer (score 2):

If the XML file is the problem (`ToLower()` is not sufficient), you can use [`translate()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315719) like this to swap uppercase for lowercase in the XML value.

```
translate(Value, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Personally I started moving XML handling over to `System.Xml.Linq`. Far more flexibility. Still fast, but simpler once you get the hang of it.

Comment: What if their IDs are using extended latin characters or other unicode?

Comment: Not a clue, never needed to find out :)

Comment: Well, it was a rhetorical question, meaning this trick won't work in these cases.

Comment: @wOxxOm It works if you include the additional uppercase and lowercase characters in the translation lists.

Comment: Well, certainly, the question would benefit from including this info, if not the actual strings with at least the accented characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use ToLower() on your $siteId variable.  That is how I usually handle making text case-insensitive -- just make sure all of the text is in one consistent format.  You can also use ToUpper() to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In addition to $siteId, we also want to convert the xml id. Can you tell me how can we do that.

Comment: The question has already `$Siteid = $Siteid.ToLower()` in the posted code, so this answer is redundant and doesn't provide the real solution.

Comment: @wOxxOm:  Oops.  You are right.  I missed that when looking over the code.

Comment: @mahesh:  Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18818734/3490275

I think the answer found at that link provides what you are looking for.